# Enable/Disable toolbar button based on active display in ExtJS panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a panel with a docked toolbar and an icon inside it. The panel has several items (accordion layout). I want to enable the icon only for selected items. I.e. when a valid item is active the button should be become enabled, and then be disabled if the user activates an item that the icon is not applicable for.

I tried `disabled: function() { some code to find whether item is valid .. }`, but that didnot work.

I also researched panel listeners to find one for item change and then use `button.setDisabled(bool)` but couldnot find the right event to use.

How do I achieve this?

p.s. I am using ExtJS 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

When you change items in an accordion, they panel that gets activated will fire the `expand` event. So listen to the expand event on each panel, then call `enable`/`disable` on the appropriate buttons.

Comment: sounds right and I tried it, but it doesnot work? sample code?

Comment: the function is not executed at the event? do I bind it to the panel or to the items? I also have my items created somewhere else in the code, would that make a different, just have ids in the panel items list.